# Building from one image and adding dependency to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, anaconda, dockerfile

**Setting**

I am building a machine learning project using Docker and I would like to use `anaconda` as my base. However this project also requires `bamos/openface`, and I would like to link to my project using `docker-compose`.

**Problem**

I do not know how to link the `openface` dependency. Right now I am actually building `FROM bamos/openface`, so my `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM bamos/openface
ADD . /face-off
WORKDIR /face-off    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
EXPOSE 5000    
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` is simply:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: face-off-web
    command: python app.py
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - .:/face-off
```

I would like to build `FROM continuumio/anaconda` and then add `openface` as a dependency in my `docker-compose` file, but I do not know what the syntax is! Or if this is even a valid thing to do!

Answer (score -1):

You can't inherit from 2 docker containers. Pick the docker container that is the most appropriate for your purposes, and then just pull in whatever extra depenencies you need with `RUN`.

Comment: that makes sense. Could I ask you to give an example of how to do that in the docker-compose file?